# How to set up the classes for a polymorphic, self-referential group of models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphism, self-reference

I'm trying to set up an application that includes groups that can be composed of users or existing groups.

Examples:

- Users *Andy*, *Bob*, *Charlie*, and *David* are in the *1st forwarders* group.
- Users *Eddy*, *Frank*, *George*, *Howard*, *Iggy*, and *Jack* are in the *1st midfielders* group.
- Users *Kenny*, *Lenny*, *Max*, *Ned*, *Oscar*, *Peter*, and *Quin* are in the *1st defenders* group.
- User *Rita* is the only user in the *1st goalkeeper* group.
- Users *Andy*, *Bob*, *Eddy*, *Frank*, and *Kenny* are also in the *alpha basketballers* group.
- Groups *1st forwarders*, *1st midfielders*, *1st defenders*, and *1st goalkeeper* are in the *1st footballers* group.
- Groups *1st forwarders*, *2nd midfielders*, *3rd defenders*, and *4th goalkeeper* are in the *all-star footballers* group.

As I understand it, this will require a polymorphic, self-referential set of models.

Based on this understanding, the three models and corresponding classes that I currently have are:

**Users**
- id: integer
- name: string
- plus other person-specific data

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :memberships, :as => :child 
  has_many :groups, :through => :memberships 
end
```

**Groups**
- id: integer
- name: string
- plus other group-specific data

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  # parental membership role
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, :through => :memberships

  # child membership role
  has_many :memberships, :as => :child  
end
```

**Memberships**
- child_id: integer
- group_id: integer
- membership_type: string
- plus other membership-specific data

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :child, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :group
end
```

When I try to access the child via something like `Membership.first.child` I always get a `=> nil` response.

Do I have my models and classes set up correctly?
  If not, what have I done incorrectly?
  If so, how do I pull the child's information?

Or am I approaching this incorrectly, and if so, how should I approach it?

Comment: How are you saving this membership model? And where are the polymorphic association columns?

Comment: @Mauricio - Currently I'm just using the console to manually create, save, and view the models' data.  

As I understand it, within the Memberships model the `child_id` and `membership_type` are the polymorphic association columns, with the `belongs_to :child, :polymorphic => true` in the Membership class and the `has_many :memberships, :as => :child` in the `User` and `Group` classes providing the other polymorphic information.  

Of course, since I can't currently access a group's child information, I'm assuming I've messed something up. ;)

Comment: Yes, you did, the polymorphic association columns should be named **child_id** and **child_type**.

Comment: @Mauricio - _Thank you!_  I clearly misunderstood several of the examples I reviewed and as a result hadn't even tried something so obvious.  Would you please post your last comment as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polymorphic association columns should be **child_id** and **child_type**.